# Can cats be ticklish?

Tags: cats, behavior

I've heard dogs have ticklish spots where they react when you tickle them there. I couldn't find any information on ticklish cats and their possible ticklish spots.

My cat tends to flick his ears if I touched the hair on the edge of his inner ear, but I'm not sure if that's a ticklish reaction or not. Do cats have ticklish spots?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by ticklish? Cats don't have a laughter reaction, so I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Zaralynda I guess the reaction I'm expecting would be "I like it when you rub there, and will encourage you to do it, but will playfully attack when you pet there. When you stop, I'll come back for more" It's hard to explain the reaction, but it would be a "I like that, but not too much of it" reaction

Comment: You can often find spots where lightly touching the tips of the fur will elicit a twitching response, which you could call a tickle.

Comment: ticling is very negative for cats and highly uncomfortable,the same is if you put your hand over a cats paws,a cat mother puts her paw on top of her kittens paw or on top of the head to tell a kitten to stop and calm down.this is universal for all cats big and small wild and domesticated,one can see this reaction when you pet a cat on its head the head moves away from the hand for a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I've seen to ticklishness is the reaction many cats have to having their paws handled -- and they seem to find it more annoying than entertaining.

I've seen cats that like "mock-threat" play with humans -- that will struggle when turned upside down or tossed and caught, for example, yet come right back for more. That isn't ticklishness as most humans would define it, but it's a similar interrupted-defense reaction.

But cats, like people, have their own quirks and opinions. All you can do is ask them whether they like something or not and pay attention to the answer.

Comment: `that will struggle when turned upside down or tossed and caught,`  - I don't believe this is acceptable play behaviour with a cat